# What are the differences between「目的」and 「目標」?

Tags: word-choice

Both「目的」and「目標」have a common meaning which is "goal", but what is the difference? 
When can we use one but not the other?

Comment: Which dictionary did you check?  Doesn't your dictionary say more than just "goal"?

Comment: It was actually in my book. For example: まず無理のない目標を立てる。 If I use 「目的」instead of 「目標」 is the meaning of sentence going to change? 

実は教科書に出てきた言葉なんです。例えば「まず無理のない目標を立てる」。もし「目標」のかわりに「目的」を使ったら意味が違うのでしょうか。

In my dictionary 目的; a purpose; 〔目標〕a goal, an objective; 〔ねらい〕an aim; 〔意図〕an intention

目標: 〔ねらい〕an aim; 〔最終目的〕a goal; 〔達成目標〕a target

By the way I'm using mac osx Lion's dictionary

Comment: Thanks.  I do not have time to think about a proper answer right now, but here are some hints.  (1) “目標を立てる” means “set a goal,” but “目的を立てる” is incorrect.  (2) Another hint is in your dictionary: what is the difference between “purpose” and “goal”?

Answer (score 12):

`目的` can also mean "purpose".  There is a book called "The Purpose Driven Life".  In Japanese, it's titled `人生を導く５つの目的`.

I think it boils down to the difference in English between "purpose" and "goal".  A goal is something finite you hope to achieve.  A purpose is like a motivation for why you do something.  Often they will overlap, but not always.  Having a finite goal kind of implies that you have a motivation.  However, the converse—having a motivation implies you have a finite goal—is not necessarily true.

Ex.

> A: Why did you come to campus today?
> B1: I came to visit my professor and get a letter of recommendation. → The goal and the motivation are the same: get the letter.
> B2: I came to visit my professor. →　The motivation of why I came to campus is to see my professor.  However, there is nothing "achievable" just by visiting him.

So the same with the Japanese words.  If you have a `目標` you also (likely) have a `目的`.  However, if you have a `目的`, you do not necessarily have a `目標`.

That's how I see them anyway.

Answer (score 7):

目的＝目標＋意味

Example:
I want to become better at shooting the basketball. => 目的
I will consider myself better at it when I score at least 50% of my shots. => 目標

目的 is a high level image, global image of a goal. 目標 is a more milestones like low level goal towards achieving the 目的 which can be quantified and is explicit.