# Difference between words 目的 /目標 and 方針

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between words 目的 ｛もくてき｝/目標｛もくひょう｝ and 方針｛ほうしん｝?　
I found a question, which explains the difference between 目的 ｛もくてき｝/目標｛もくひょう｝( [What are the differences between「目的」and 「目標」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9790/what-are-the-differences-between-%E7%9B%AE%E7%9A%84-and-%E7%9B%AE%E6%A8%99) ), but I wonder how to distinguish them from the word 方針｛ほうしん｝.

Answer (score 2):

目的 or 目標 is a sort of objective, you can get it and get to it.  It's concrete one.  方針 is not a goal but where you face or what methods you choose.  You can't reach it because 方針 is not what you want.

I have a sort of 目標.  I have decided the 方針 in order to achive my 目標.